# WCF detect if ServiceHost is available

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

I've got 2 C# applications that communicate via WCF, one has a `ServiceHost` singleton object with a `NetNamedPipeBinding` end point, the client creates an instance of the exposed interface via a `DuplexChannelFactory.CreateChannel()` call. Sometimes my client will start before my server and so the client needs to know whether the server is available. The `CreateChannel()` call succeeds regardless but subsequent calls to the interface functions fail with an exception. Once a call has failed, any calls after that fail with an error that the channel is faulted. Is my only option to catch these exceptions and create a new channel each time or is there a better way?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 3):

A channel can get faulted at any time for a number of reasons like network failure. Which means that the answer is yes, you need to handle faulted channels.

I usually create a new channel each time that I need one (I register my channels with transient/scoped lifetime in my inversion of control container).

Comment: That's what I was expecting, just wanted to see if there was some magic `IsAvailable()` method that I should be using. Thanks.

Comment: There might be something like that, but not that I know of.

Comment: @JWood: no there's no such method - plus, even if there were - that only tells you if the channel's there **right now** - a split second later, it could be gone already (cable disconnected, server going down - you name it). Therefore it's pretty pointless having something like that - you **always** need to be prepared to handle exceptions when working with WCF...